# nested fragments

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, fragment

Is it possible to nest fragment in ICS?. I mean can we inflate a layout xml file which contains one or more fragments and give it to parent fragment view using Fragment.onCreateView?

Answer (score 6):

Now it's supported, read the following info http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Answer (score 0):

i think it works but not on Android 2.x.
i've tried this with the support library and got a inflate exception

Comment: It is possible to implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.